# TFS 2010 Build based on Work items

Tags: tfs

Scenario: Dev team has lets say 10 Work items. They resolve 8 work items and that needed changes to 50 files (checked out and checked in and during check in are associated to Work Items). They also worked on remaining 2 work items and fixed and checked in 5 files, but the work items are not completely done, so not resolved yet. Now I want to create a build with the 50 files only which are associated to the 8 Resolved Work items (and exclude from build the 5 files for the 2 unresolved bugs) . Is there a way to do that in TFS 2010?

Answer (score 0):

TFS builds from changesets, so you need to find out the changesets associated with the work items you need to include/exclude. Simply browsing the history may suffice, but you may have to inspect what changesets are associated with the work items.

- if you're lucky those changesets that you don't want to have included in the build are later in History, it's simply a matter of setting up a workspace containing only the history up until the changeset you need. If you're using Team Build, the default build process has parameter `GetVersion` that you can set to the changeset you want to build when queuing. If it's manual, you'll have to do a

  `tf get /version:C<changeset number>`
- **(UPDATED)** If on the other hand the order of checkins have been mixed (some of the changes that you need to exclude have been done prior to some that you need to include), the best way would be to create a branch, and then only merge the changesets you need to include to that branch. Then you can simply build from the latest version on that branch.

  1)Using History, find the latest changeset with code you need (the closest prior to one you need to exclude)
  2) Create a branch based on that version.
  3) Do a selective merge of the other changesets you will need included in your build, skipping those you don't want.
  4) Build from the Latest version on that branch.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. My scenario would be where some of the changes that I need to exclude have been done prior to some that I need to include. We are not using Team Build. Can we use "Get Specific Version" and give the Changeset numbers there? Will that work?

Comment: Is it fairly easy to work with branches and merges if I have to do a daily build? Because one thing which I observed with branching is I need to change the references again when I do a branch - which can become tedious if I have to do builds on a daily basis. Also Do you know of a good document around branching/merging?

Comment: No, this is not a viable method on a daily basis. As this seems to be the case, I'd strongly suggest you to adapt the development and build process to "reverse" the scenario. Have developers work on a development branch, and when they're done with a task have them merge that to an integration branch (since they make the changes, they should do the merge). Build from the integration branch whenever there's a checkin made there.